# Posting data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm rank new to javascript and React, thus the question.
I need to post data from inside a component.
I'm using the fetch API for POST. This is my code.

```
export function postData(url, sender, media){
  return fetch(url, { headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                      credentials: 'include',
                      method: 'POST',
                      body: JSON.stringify({sender: sender, media: media})
  })
    .then((response) => { return response.json() ;})
    .catch((error) =>{ console.log("Request failed: ", error) ;})

}
```

Inside my component I have two methods that get the values that I intend posting from callbacks in child components.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{

..........
handleClick(sender){
    console.log(data);

  }

  handleSubmit(media){
    console.log(data);
  }
......
render(){
......
passing down handleSubmit and handleClick as props to child
    }
}
```

How and where in the component do I call my `postData` method and how do I pass `sender` and `media`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `click` and `submit` are separate events, so you'll have to architect things a little differently if you want them to both be passed.

As far as calling `postData`, it looks like you have to

```
import { postData } from foo;
```

...at the top of the `MyComponent` file, so the function becomes available.  Once you have `postData` imported properly, you can use it inside your event handler function.

I just skimmed your `fetch`  but looks like it should be fine, or at least easy to debug.

---

In summary: fix it so you have one event handler, which will be passed `media` and `sender` as arguments.  Then, import `postData` and call it in the handler.

Comment: How can I put media and sender into  1 event handler since they are two separate events in two child components.

Comment: You'll have to store them in the component state.  Read up on "component state" and wire up your child components accordingly.  I'm a tad fuzzy on this because I've been using Redux for a while, which manages your state all in one place, but is probably too much for this simple project.  Anyway, research on component state and refs will get you where you want to be :)